# How to convert QScriptValue to QVariantList in Blackberry Qt C++

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-qnx

it is my code for conversion from QScriptValue to QVariantList .But i am getting error on the last line. please correct me if i am doing something wrong.

```
    void ApplicationUI::onResult(QNetworkReply* reply)
    {

        if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
            return;  // ...only in a blog post
        }
        QString data = (QString) reply->readAll();
        QScriptEngine engine;
        QScriptValue result = engine.evaluate("(" + data + ")");
        QScriptValue entries = result.property("result");


        QVariantList *mainListd=entries.toVariant().toList();

}
```

I want to insert this mainListd in GroupDataModel.

Comment: I guess your data is formated in JSON? If so, ``QScriptValue`` is maybe not the right way to do it, as you can use ``JsonDataAccess`` to parse JSON data.

Comment: Yes you are right JsonDataAccess is one of the best way to parse . but if i do in the required way then i solve my problem by removing pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QVariant::toList()` returns a `QList<QVariant>`. You're trying to store it in a `QVariantList*`, which is in fact a `QList<QVariant>*`. You shouldn't be using a pointer here.